# Sharepoint view to show subfolder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, view

I'm in sharepoint 2010 and have a document library with folder and subfolder inside.
I'd like to show immediately the subfolder in the view.

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to edit the page in SharePoint Designer.

1. Browse to the view you want to add the treeview to.
2. Edit the page in SharePoint Designer — then Click Advanced Mode.
3. Add a table to PlaceHolderMain with one row and Two Columns
4. Move the Existing Webpart Zone (the one that contains the view) and allits content to the second td you just added.
5. Add the following to the first TD you just added(the one whose width is 20%)
6. Change the RootListId attribute of the SPHierarchyDataSourceControl to whatever is in the ListID Attribute of the XsltListViewWebPart in the second TD.
7. Change the RootWebId attribute of the SPHierarchyDataSourceControl to the WebID of the Web the list is in (I used SharePoint manager to get the web ID)

[Source](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/10/22/add-a-treeview-to-a-document-library-using-sptreeview-and-sphierarchicaldatasource-aspx-2/)

Comment: Not sure why the code isn't showing up in my answer. Just follow the source link for full details.